# Queue, mutex и threads

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Есть одна ошибка

`Error  3   error C2280: 'std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function`

Её надо починить. Как она возникает? Есть один класс, который реализует очередь. В самом конце. Я почитал документацию, что mutex копировать нельзя. Хорошо. Я передаю в функцию ссылку на этот объект. Но к сожалению ловлю эту ошибку.

---

**Функция `main()`**

```
int main()
{
   Queue<MyStruct> tasks; //создаем объект
   std::thread t1(buildQueue, tasks); //кидаем ссылку 
   return 0;
}
void buildQueue(Queue<MyStruct> &taskQueue)
{
 ; //ничего не делает. 
}
```

**Класс Queue**

```
template <typename T> class Queue{

private:
    const unsigned int MAX = 5;
    std::deque<T>           newQueue;
    std::mutex              d_mutex;
    std::condition_variable d_condition;

public:
    void push(T const& value)
    {

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
            newQueue.push_front(value);
        }
        this->d_condition.notify_one();
    }
    T pop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
        this->d_condition.wait(lock, [=]{ return !this->newQueue.empty(); });
        T rc(std::move(this->newQueue.back()));
        this->newQueue.pop_back();
        return rc;
    }   
};
```

Где-то читал, что такая проблема возникает в том, что вызывает конструктор, который пытается копировать mutex. Хотя я, вроде бы, ничего не копирую.

Comment: А что есть `MyStruct`? Это важно. И ещё, приведите строку, в которой ошибка.

Comment: Да просто для теста. `struct MyStruct { int test; };` Туда будут данные помещаться, а сама структура будет попадать в список.

Comment: Окей, с этим хорошо. А в какой строке ошибка?

Comment: [Такие дела](http://i.imgur.com/01J5RGz.png)

Comment: Ыыы?.. Тогда приведите полное сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: `Error 3 error C2280: 'std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function microsoft\visual studio\vc\include\xlocnum 155 1 Thread_test`

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22634/discussion-between-ascelhem-and-vladd).

Answer (score 2):

```
std::thread t1(buildQueue, std::ref(tasks)); 
t1.join();
```

Comment: Изменил. Все равно такая же ошибка.

Comment: Попробуйте так `std::thread t1(buildQueue, std::ref(tasks)); t1.join();`

Comment: Без понятия, где вы это нашли, но это заработало. Что тут вообще происходит? Это какой-то костыль?

Comment: Так как функция buildQueue будет выполняться в новом потоке, конструктор std::thread выполняет копирование объекта tasks. Чтобы копировалась ссылка, а не объект, используется std::ref (или std::cref для константных объектов).
Это написано здесь http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/thread/
после описания параметров

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в этой строчке:

```
std::thread t1(buildQueue, tasks);
```

Здесь Вы передаёте `tasks` по значение, следовательно происходит попытка его копирования в объект `t1`. Но это невозможно выполнить, т.к. `std::mutex` не может быть скопирован(у него удалён конструктор копирования).

Проще всего обернуть `tasks` в `std::shared_ptr` и уже его передавать в поток. Поидее, следующий код тоже должен работать:

```
std::thread t1(buildQueue, std::move(tasks));
```

Но беглый осмотр различных компиляторов показал, что они отказываются это делать. Причина, лично мне, не ясна. Скорее всего везде баги.

Comment: Ниже в посте предложили использовать std::ref(tasks) - работает. std::move выдает такую же ошибку.

Comment: @Ascelhem, передача ссылки на локальную переменную в другой поток не самая лучшая идея.

Comment: Какие вообще идеи по реализации очереди? У меня есть одна очередь, в которую помещаются объекты, а ими уже пользуется другая функция. Поэтому я создал класс Queue, который хранит и позволяет манипулировать очередью.

Comment: Ну у Вас идея правильная, просто я бы передавал в разные потоки очередь обёрнутую в умный указатель. Это позволяет забыть о ёё времени жизни. Из того, что я вижу, Вы пытаетесь изобразить concurrent queue. Но это давно решённая задача и, в зависимости от требуемого компилятора, может быть решена готовыми средствами. Как-то boost.lockfree - для кроссплатформы или же [concurrent_queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355358.aspx) от MS, если достаточно студии.